# Curiosity: How WPF controls, canvas and panels clip work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clip

i can't understand how the panels clip their children. I try to better explain.

If I have a groupbox and I add a button as its children from the editor, the button is not clipped if it exceed the group bounds. So the button is complety visible.

If I add another button in runtime from code, the button get clipped. If I set clip to bounds = true nothing change.

If I add a Canvas panel and then the button (always in runtime), the button (and I think also the canvas) is not clipped. (Groupbox -> canvas -> button)

Why canvas aren't clipped? Why controls added in runtime yes and in editor not?

Comment: I have the described canvas effect too. Did you find a solution for this behaviour?